# php - property of not declared object

Tags: php, yii

I find this code when Yii gen the views file :

```
<?php
   $this->breadcrumbs=array(
      'Deal'=>array('deal/index'),
      'Create',
   );?>
   <h1><?php echo $this->id . '/' . $this->action->id; ?></h1>

   <p>You may change the content of this page by modifying the file <tt><?php echo __FILE__; ?></tt>.</p>
```

I know $this is actually an object but I don't see any include or object declare, how come we have that $this->id ?

I'm very new to PHP and also very excited to learn it too :). Thanks first.

Comment: A good reason to not use `$this` in templates.

Comment: You might want to work through a couple of the Yii tutorials http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorials/ if you haven't already to get a feel for the framework and how it's organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii uses the following view renderer (in CBaseController):

```
public function renderInternal($_viewFile_,$_data_=null,$_return_=false)
    {
        // we use special variable names here to avoid conflict when extracting data
        if(is_array($_data_))
            extract($_data_,EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,'data');
        else
            $data=$_data_;
        if($_return_)
        {
            ob_start();
            ob_implicit_flush(false);
            require($_viewFile_);
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        else
            require($_viewFile_);
    }
```

As you can see your view is called inside the context of the controller and therefore has access to $this (controller). Whilst it is considered bad practice to pass data view using the controller it is useful for parsing data between through views and accessing other functionality (such as widgets).

In your code sample the property breadcrumbs of the controller may be modified by the view and read by the layout even though the view is inside the layout. This works because the view is rendered and then inserted into the layout. Also worth noting that using this is the only way to pass data to layouts from the controller.

Although yii's documentation is great there is nothing better than opening up the source and having a look at how it works. After all, that's the whole point of open source :D

Answer (score 1):

Many times frameworks will load views into objects and then render them. This is one of those times. In this case, based on how CViewRenderer works and renderInternal works, it will be a CBaseController instance, and (more oft than not) the current CController instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is included inside a function(inside an object), meaning that your are in the scope of the object.

Every inclusion in php will let u use the variables inside the "includer", in your case, $this is a valid variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible this file is included or something in a class method. If it is included it will be possible to use $this if the method is not static, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've provided (unless there is more) `$this->id` doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

for debugging/understanding purpose you could call a

```
var_dump($this)
```

or a

```
print_r($this)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii and the context you present (a view file) "$this" represents the Controller object. The "id" is the name of the controller, so if it was a view file rendered by the SiteController, "$this->id" would = "site". Not surprising then, "$this->action->id" = the action name.

Are you getting some kind of error or just wondering what it refers to? As mentioned, you can print out the contents of the object with `print_r($this)` .